# I have problems importing data with DataFrames in Julia Language

Tags: julia

I do not know how to solve it please help me

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> readtable("/home/ronald/Documentos/csv/model.csv")
Error showing value of type DataFrames.DataFrame:
ERROR: type TypeName has no field wrapper
 in display(::Media.DisplayHook, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at /home/ronald/.julia/v0.6/Media/src/compat.jl:9
 in display(::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ./multimedia.jl:184
 in print_response(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Any, ::Void, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Void) at ./REPL.jl:156
 in print_response(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Any, ::Void, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./REPL.jl:141
 in (::Base.REPL.##22#23{Bool,Base.REPL.##33#42{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL,Base.REPL.REPLHistoryProvider},Base.REPL.LineEditREPL,Base.LineEdit.Prompt})(::Base.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at ./REPL.jl:654
 in run_interface(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Base.LineEdit.ModalInterface) at ./LineEdit.jl:1579
 in run_frontend(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackendRef) at ./REPL.jl:931
 in run_repl(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Base.##964#965) at ./REPL.jl:190
 in _start() at ./client.jl:377
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHolw.png)

Comment: and what is inside "/home/ronald/Documentos/csv/model.csv"?

Comment: check Pkd.dir() * "DataFrames/test/data" to see a list of sample .csv files, you could copy one and modify it ...

Comment: You should try with Julia version 0.5 (the current stable version) instead of 0.6, which is the development version.